# How to split multiple filters into multiple lines with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, multiline, ansible-filter

Here's a task I have on my playbook:

```
- name: Parse 'LANGUAGE' from current locale and language configuration
  set_fact:
    locale_language: "{{ locale_status.stdout | regex_search('LANGUAGE=([^\n]+)', '\\1') | default([locale_lang], true) | first }}"
```

I'm trying to find a way to split that multiple filters line into multiple lines to make it more readable, but nothing I do works. Is it even possible without making the whole thing more complicated to read?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
- name: Parse 'LANGUAGE' from current locale and language configuration
  set_fact:
    locale_language: "{{ locale_status.stdout \
                     | regex_search('LANGUAGE=([^\n]+)', '\\1') \
                     | default([locale_lang], true) \
                     | first }}"
```

As I have tested this below task and it works fine,

```
tasks:
    - set_fact:
        locale_language: "{{ shubham \
                         | quote }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ locale_language }}"
```

Comment: @RicardoAmaral, If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept the answer to mark this question as answered.

Comment: best choice for long `lookup` jinja expressions (feeding directly to the `yaml` parser still doesn't work)

Answer (score 4):

Once Jinja parsing starts, (to the best of my knowledge and experience) it becomes whitespace insensitive; so, just use the normal [YAML scalar line folding](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2779048) construct and you're off to the races:

```
locale_language: >-
  {{- locale_status.stdout
  | regex_search('LANGUAGE=([^\n]+)', '\\1')
  | default([locale_lang], true)
  | first -}}
```

The use of ["whitespace consuming operators"](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#whitespace-control) at the start and end of the Jinja expressions is at your discretion (and depends, of course, on whether the ultimate fact is tolerant of whitespace or not)

Comment: Didn't work, I got this `An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
fatal: [POLYMERBOX]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}`.